# Cordova Facebook Connect

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I have spent 3 days trying to figure out this issue but unfortunately so far no solution.
I am using Cordova 3.4.0-0.1.3
Using https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect to have the facebook connect functionality.
I have added the following code in my config.xml

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
</feature>
```

But I keep on getting following error

> ERROR: Plugin 'FacebookConnect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could guide me to a link to basic tutorial or help me resolve this issue. And kindly also let me know if I implement facebook connect like its done for a website will that work in the same manner or is there any difference in both methods.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have Cordova Facebook Connect Working on your project is to use plugman install:

cordova create myApp

cd myApp/

cordova platform add ios

cordova -d plugin add phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"

Comment: Is that all or will I need to do anything more than that in order to get it working?

Comment: For iOS nothing more required, but for android you have to reference the FacebookSDK project as a library to your project.

Comment: Ok giving it a shot right now. Thanks let me get back to you with how it goes

Comment: Still gives this error ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

Comment: and weird part is that this time its not even named that in config.xml
 <feature name="FacebookConnectPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>

Comment: Weird indeed, Try to clean your config.xml file from any trace of Facebook plugin and remove the plugin 'cordova plugin remove phonegap-facebook-plugin' and reinstall again 'cordova -d plugin add phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication" '

Comment: ok well i tried the same thing by creating a completely new project. And it did the same thing.

Following are the references lines added by the plugin

    <feature name="FacebookConnectPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <plugin name="FacebookConnectPlugin" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />